# TextBox: how to get rid of limitation on number of rows?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a multiline textbox, and by default it has rows="2". But I want the textbox to grow or shrink based on the contents. I don't want the textbox be too large or too small. Could you please tell me how I could do that?
Thanks, David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the javascript method from [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/coltk/archive/2010/05/30/expandable-or-auto-resize-textbox-height.aspx).

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMsg" runat="server"  TextMode="MultiLine" style="overflow:hidden" onkeyup="AutoExpand(this, event)" Rows="2" />


 function AutoExpand(txtBox, event
 {
     if (event.keyCode == "13" || event.keyCode == "8") {
        var therows = 0
        var thetext = document.getElementById(txtBox.id).value;
        var newtext = thetext.split("\n");
        therows += newtext.length

        document.getElementById(txtBox.id).rows = therows;
        return false;
     }
 }
```

Comment: So there is no simple attribute or style for the textbox that would do that without javascript? Thanks.